# How I can put a link to a menu on a CircleAvatar? Is possible?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I have a circleAvatar widget and I want put something like a link that redirect in my Avatar a other menu.

I think something like a onPressed() but this is only in Icon widget.

Comment: Try adding some code of what you already tried. btb, try using `InkWell` widget with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have non clickable widgets, use a `GestureDetector`, this widget allows you to react to events like tap, pan, double tap, long press and so on...

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Your code here!!!!
  },
  child: YourCircleAvatarWidget(),
)
```

Check the [docs page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inkwell`
for example,

```
           InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                   // do something here
                 },
                child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://a.githubusercontent.com/u/a?s=460&v=4'),
            ),
           ),
```